# gRaphael dynamically/live updating charts

Tags: javascript, charts, dynamic-data, graphael

I am new to gRaphael and because of the poor documentation , would like to ask this simple question.

I have to make dynamically/live updating charts and am considering using gRaphael , can someone guide me how can we dynamically load / update data for say , a `line chart`.

Or some other good alternative that **someone has a good experience with**  for a similar use would be very helpful.Thanks.

Comment: take a look at jqplot http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barLineAnimated.html main page http://www.jqplot.com/

Comment: I want to do the same for a dot-chart. Someone has done it for a bar-chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/MVwwq/86/ Basically they create another hidden chart with the next data series, copy the paths for animation from that, hide it, and animate the first chart to the new path values. You have to take care of the hover function as well